# How to update listview by dropdown?

Tags: php, yii

I need to update listview after selecting the drop-down-list.
I have drop-down in index.php file

```
<?php echo CHtml::DropDownList('myDropDown1','',array(),array(

        'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiListView.update(
           'ajaxListView', {url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl('RepotCardMain/getclassreportcards')."?myDropDown1='+$('#myDropDown1 option:selected').val()})",
        'prompt'=>' select a Class','style'=>'width:300px;'
        ));
```

listview is

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 
    'itemView'=>'_view',
        'id'=>'ajaxListView',
)); ?>
```

In my RepotCardMainController.php i have getclassreportcards method

```
 if(isset($_POST['myDropDown1']))
    {

       $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
       $criteria->condition = 't.class_id=:class_id';
       $criteria->params    = array(':class_id'=>$_POST['myDropDown1']);
       $dataProvider=new      CActiveDataProvider('RepotCardMain',array('criteria'=>$criteria,));

        $this->render('repotCardMain',array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
    }
```

this is not updating the listview and i couldn't error.I need a quick help for this. 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` since you passed the param `myDropDown1` as  a querystring

Edited: Since you provide less information which let I look inside, I will portray how it work
for you
[image]

Comment: but no change the same problem.

Comment: can you tell me is this is correct. i debug the programmer and debuger didn't go to this url 'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiListView.update(
           'ajaxListView', {url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl('RepotCardMain/getclassreportcards')."?myDropDown1='+$('#myDropDown1 option:selected').val()})",

Comment: Did you try to console.log the response what ajax request returned back? Was it success or fail? Or you did change the selected value from the drop down then event even did not fire? What is in view repotCardMain?

Comment: It says "
[22:24:07.039] Empty string passed to getElementById()"

Comment: and requesting 
[22:23:55.780] GET http://localhost/dinamic/index.php?r=&ajax=ajaxListView [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 10019ms] how can i fix this

Comment: HTTP 200 OK is not error, it means that your ajax request is running OK. What I concern about the Response instead, did it return the HTML of child-view.php like my screen shot (included on my answer)?